# PHP explode formatted text to array

Tags: php

I'm trying to get some Jade formatted layout format from http://shoelace.io/ parsed in PHP
I have this formatted text

```
.row.rowname
  .boxname.col-sm-4
  .boxtwo.col-sm-4
  .boxthree.col-sm-4
.row.therowbelowhasnoname
  .theboxbelowhasnoname.col-sm-8
  .col-sm-4
.row
  .col-sm-4
  .col-sm-8
```

which I want to explode into a multidimensional array
somthing like.

```
Array
(
    [rowname] => Array
        (
            [col] => Array
                (
                    [coltype] => col-sm-4
                    [colname] => boxname
                )

            [col] => Array
                (
                    [coltype] => col-sm-4
                    [colname] => boxtwo
                )
        )
    [therowbelowhasnoname] => Array
        (
            [col] => Array
                (
                    [coltype] => col-sm-8
                    [colname] => theboxbelowhasnoname
                )

            [col] => Array
                (
                    [coltype] => col-sm-4
                    [colname] => boxtwo
                )
        )
)
```

How would I go about this.
If I explode with just newlines ('\n') I lose the double spaces for the col's

Comment: Explode is only a very small step in doing what you want, and may not be usable in this case.  You are after a very specific array structure, which explode does not support "out of the box"

Comment: I think manual iteration of your new lines followed by some simple pattern matching would suffice.

Comment: You'll need to explode on `\n` as you mention, then iterate over each member of the array and do some string and/or RegEx comparison, with appropriate logic

Comment: Can't have multiple `col` keys, and `rowname` piece would have to be unique as well.

Comment: Why don't you look for e Jade parser or class to work with.  Anytime you ask yourself a question like "How do I parse the Jade formatted file?", one of the first things you should do is see if some solution already exists rather than re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you wanted in [col], but I made it an array

```
$string = ".row.rowname
  .boxname.col-sm-4
  .boxtwo.col-sm-4
  .boxthree.col-sm-4
.row.therowbelowhasnoname
  .theboxbelowhasnoname.col-sm-8
  .col-sm-4
.row
  .col-sm-4
  .col-sm-8";

$array = array();
$lastindex = null;
$continueuntillfound = null;
foreach(explode(PHP_EOL,$string) as $item)
{
  if($continueuntillfound and $item != $continueuntillfound)
    continue;
  $continueuntillfound = null;
  if($item == '.row')
  {
    $continueuntillfound = '.row.';
    continue;
  }
  elseif(strpos($item,'.row.') === 0)
  {
    $lastindex = substr($item,5);
    $array[$lastindex] = array();
  }
  elseif($lastindex and $explode = explode('.',$item) and count($explode) > 2)
  {
    $array[$lastindex][] = array('coltype' => $explode[2],'colname' => $explode[1]);
  }
  elseif($explode = explode('.',$item))
  {
    $array[$lastindex][] = array('coltype' => $explode[1],'colname' => 'boxtwo');
  }
}

print_r($array);
```

Comment: which `boxtwo` is that? the first or the last? I wasn't sure if `.row` was part of your output. is the `.col-sm-4` row supposed to get ignored?

Comment: it was the first.
your new code works.
But i suppose since keynames have to be unique i'd have to set the colname instead of just col

Comment: Note that `'colname' => 'boxtwo'` is hard coded as I wasn't sure what rule i needed to make that last one match your original output :)

Comment: Ah, row and col- are the only things not changing.
I need to get the colname and the col-* out of it

Comment: Well I hope this gives you some direction to solving your problem, Please accept this answer if it helped you.

Comment: its something little but i still get some newlines on coltype
`string(9) "col-sm-4
"`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48313/discussion-between-olivier-langelaar-and-scuzzy)

Comment: @OlivierLangelaar See chat

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I'd try and find a jade parser instead of building my own.

Now, if you still want to try on your own, the first step would be to preg_split the text using \n.row (this means the text .row preceded by a new line). I'd also add a blank line at the beggining so it captures the first .row

```
$text=".row.rowname
  .boxname.col-sm-4
  .boxtwo.col-sm-4
  .boxthree.col-sm-4
.row.therowbelowhasnoname
  .theboxbelowhasnoname.col-sm-8
  .col-sm-4
.row
  .col-sm-4
  .col-sm-8";



$tarray=preg_split("/\n\.row/","\n".$text,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($tarray);
```